# MapView not working [android]

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

i have a little trouble with the android mapview. It simply crashes every time i try to open the app!
Code:

```
package com.jappapps.android.travelbuddy;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class TravelBuddy extends MapActivity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main); // changed to lowercase
       MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); // match id in main.xml
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.jappapps.android.travelbuddy"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".TravelBuddy"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
 </manifest>
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0QrW-CcUIzU_fxIS_9O-BkFnuPC-rTj-7t3Q0xw"
/>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` line should be inside the `<application>` tags

Comment: Works perfectly! Just have to integrate POI and tabs to finish up my app :)

Comment: My problem was a little different: The <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> tab was INSIDE of the application tag when it should be outside. But I got there because of your answer. Thanks!